# Kafka long coordinator load time and small ISRs

Tags: apache-kafka, pykafka

I'm using Kafka 0.8.2.1, running a topic with 200 partitions and RF=3, with log retention set to about 1GB.

An unknown event caused the cluster to enter the "coordinator load" or "group load" state. A few signals made this apparent: the pykafka-based consumers began to fail during `FetchOffsetRequest`s with error code 14 `COORDINATOR_LOAD_IN_PROGRESS` for some subset of partitions. These errors were triggered when consuming with a consumer group that had existed since before the coordinator load. In broker logs, messages like this appeared:

```
[2018-05...] ERROR Controller 17 epoch 20 initiated state change for partition [my.cool.topic,144] from OnlinePartition to OnlinePartition failed (state.change.logger)
kafka.common.StateChangeFailedException: encountered error while electing leader for partition [my.cool.topic,144] due to: Preferred replica 11 for partition [my.cool.topic,144] is either not alive or not in the isr. Current leader and ISR: [{"leader":12,"leader_epoch":7,"isr":[12,13]}].
```

For some reason, Kafka decided that replica 11 was the "preferred" replica despite the fact that it was not in the ISR. To my knowledge, consumption could continue uninterrupted from either replica 12 or 13 while 11 resynchronized - it's not clear why Kafka chose a non-synced replica as the preferred leader.

The above-described behavior lasted for about 6 hours, during which the pykafka fetch_offsets error made message consumption impossible. While the coordinator load was still in progress, other consumer groups were able to consume the topic without error. In fact, the eventual fix was to restart the broken consumers with a new consumer_group name.

Questions

1. Is it normal or expected for the coordinator load state to last for 6 hours? Is this load time affected by log retention settings, message production rate, or other parameters?
2. Do non-pykafka clients handle `COORDINATOR_LOAD_IN_PROGRESS` by consuming only from the non-erroring partitions? Pykafka's insistence that all partitions return successful `OffsetFetchResponse`s can be a source of consumption downtime.
3. Why does Kafka sometimes select a non-synced replica as the preferred replica during coordinator loads? How can I reassign partition leaders to replicas in the ISR?
4. Are all of these questions moot because I should just be using a newer version of Kafka?

Broker config options:

```
broker.id=10
port=9092
zookeeper.connect=****/kafka5

log.dirs=*****
delete.topic.enable=true
replica.fetch.max.bytes=1048576
replica.fetch.wait.max.ms=500
replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms=5000
replica.socket.timeout.ms=30000
replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes=65536
replica.lag.time.max.ms=10000
replica.lag.max.messages=4000
controller.socket.timeout.ms=30000
message.max.bytes=1000000
auto.create.topics.enable=false
log.index.interval.bytes=4096
log.index.size.max.bytes=10485760
log.retention.hours=96
log.roll.hours=168
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
zookeeper.sync.time.ms=2000
num.io.threads=8
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
num.replica.fetchers=4
controller.message.queue.size=10
num.partitions=8
log.flush.interval.ms=60000
log.flush.interval.messages=60000
log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms=2000
num.network.threads=8
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=1048576
socket.send.buffer.bytes=1048576
queued.max.requests=500
fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=100
producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=100
controlled.shutdown.enable=true
```

Comment: Replicas that are not in sync can be chosen as leader of unclean leader election is enabled. Looks like this is the case for you. For everything else, I'd really recommend moving to a newer version, ideally 1.1. The controller is so much better since this version and you'd benefit from community knowledge. 0.8.2.1 users have mostly long since upgraded so you won't find many in the community digging into details in it anymore.

Comment: Thanks @dawsaw. Do you mean that if unclean leader election were *disabled*, Kafka might select one of the members of the ISR (12 or 13) as leader instead of repeatedly attempting to use a non-synced replica (11), which leads to an error?

Comment: Yes, if unclean leader election is disabled, it will never choose a leader that is not in the in sync replica list. You can always enable it if you end up having a need to (this happens sometimes if say you bring down the whole cluster while your are having replication issues).